# jQuery Complete Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jQuery script that uses .animate to change the background color. I used the complete event to alert("hello"), so that once the animation completed it would do the alert. But it seems it alerts as soon as it's done processing the animation. Not as it's actually finished. Is there anyway to run a function as soon as the animation ends?

Comment: Yes there is a way. Use the callback function. It's already in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I do use the callback function, but it alerts as soon as it is initiated. Rather than when the animation is completed itself, I want something similar to that that calls when it actually finishes.

Comment: **Show your code.** You seem to be using the callback incorrectly. It's impossible to help when you don't post any code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the complete (callback) function like so:

```
$(function(){
   $( "#test" ).animate({
      opacity: 0.25,
    }, 1500, function() {
      alert('hello'); // callback
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvv7vevr/)

I can't see why it wouldn't work (or why it would fire immediately) unless maybe your animation duration is very short? Edit your question and add some code

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
If supplied, the complete callback function is fired once the animation is complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one. [DEMO at JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wuvixa/1/)

```
   alert('start animation');
$('.demoDiv').animate({
     width: '90%',
   },
   { duration: 5000,
     complete: function(){
        alert('end animation');
    }
});
```